# calling jar from another jar

Tags: user-interface, jar

i am making a java swing Gui which i will convert to a jar file. also i have 3 other jar files which i am calling through my gui. But when i convert my gui and other three jar files into one, an error is shown the the 3 jar files are not found/file not found exception.
i am usin classLoader to get path of my 3 jars inside my final jar
 my code:

```
Runnable runner = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
ClassLoader cl=this.getClass().getClassLoader();
String k=cl.getResource("jar_1.jar");
Runtime.getRuntime.exec("java -jar "+k );
similary other 3 jar files..
```

so what i think is that when i convert my gui and all the other three jars into one jar then the path of the 3 jars is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Thats not how you call jars.

If they are loaded correctly you have complete control of them within your main class / jar file. and you can just import them as you would with any other import.

When they are imported you can call the methods you like (if you just want to run it - just call main() )

You should be using the class path

```
Class-Path: jar1-name jar2-name directory-name/jar3-name
```

Comment: i just want to run these other 3 jar files so can you plz suggest how should i call them...

Comment: by importing them and running their main method

Comment: can u plz tell how to do that